# Putting sum in Parent td using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have following `table` and I want to put `sum` of child table `input` into `parent` `td` input

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="gvSPActivities" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            TextVal1
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            TextVal2
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            TextVal3
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridrow2">
        <td>
            <input name="gvSPActivities$ctl02$TextVal1" type="text" id="gvSPActivities_TextVal1_0"
                class="numeric" style="width: 150px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="gvSPActivities$ctl02$TextVal2" type="text" id="gvSPActivities_TextVal2_0"
                class="numeric" style="width: 150px;" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="gvSPActivities$ctl02$TextVal3" type="text" id="gvSPActivities_TextVal3_0"
                class="total" style="width: 150px;" />

        <table>

       <tr>
           <td>
                        <input name="gvSPActivities$ctl02$gvBenefic$ctl02$txtMaleBenefic" type="text" id="gvSPActivities_gvBenefic_0_txtMaleBenefic_0" class="numeric" style="width:100px;" />
                        </td><td>
                        <input name="gvSPActivities$ctl02$gvBenefic$ctl02$txtFemaleBenefic" type="text" id="gvSPActivities_gvBenefic_0_txtFemaleBenefic_0" class="numeric" style="width:100px;" />
                        </td>

                </tr>


</table>
            </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is terribly obfuscated but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$(".gridrow2 td input").onkeyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $(".gridrow2 :input").each(function() {
        sum += $(this).val();
    });

    $("#gvSPActivities_gvBenefic_0_txtMaleBenefic_0").val(sum);
});
```

It changes the value of the "parent `<td>` input" to the sum of the three children inputs. I think.

Comment: Why are you giving me a fiddle? :)

Comment: Well, that's not the code I gave you. That's why it wouldn't work, probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = 0;

$('table > td.gridrow2 > table > td').each(function() {
  result += parseInt($(this).find('input.numeric').val());
});

$('td.gridrow2 > td:eq(2) > input[name="gvSPActivities$ctl02$TextVal3"]').val(result);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when do you want to update the total but you can use this code.

```
$('.gridrow2').each(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find('table > .numeric').each(function(){
        total += this.value;
    });

    $(this).find('.total').val(total);
});
```